weird graphql query issue
i have a full stack app that is built in PHP, MySQL, GraphQL, and Reactjs, i make the graphqql requests using fetch, my app works pretty well locally with no issues at all, and i wanted to host it on a free host to showcase it to an employer, but here the issues began, i had a query that takes a variable id and get's products that's associated with category of that id, it works only if the category with 2, if it's 3 i get an error saying unexpected end of json input.
, i tried my best to debug it and find where the error is but no clue, here's my query
query($id: ID!) {
        category(id: $id) {
            id
            name
            products {
                id
                name
                inStock: in_stock
                gallery
                description
                attributes: attribute_sets {
                    id
                    name
                    type
                    items: attributes {
                        displayValue: display_value
                        value
                        id
                    }
                }
                prices {
                    amount
                    currency {
                        symbol
                        label
                    }
                }
                brand
            }
        }
    }

